# Cannot use BuildContext Extesion in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the device theme mode using `MediaQuery.of(this).platformBrightness`. But it's giving me a Flutter Exception:

```
FlutterError (No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.
ClienteApp widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor
```

Some of my code:

```
extension DarkMode on BuildContext {
  bool get isDarkMode {
    final brightness = MediaQuery.of(this).platformBrightness;
    return brightness == Brightness.dark;
  }
}
```

theme file:

```
class Styles {
  static ThemeData themeData(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(
      primaryColor: ThemeColors.primary,
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
        primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFF199BF1, primaryColor),
        brightness: context.isDarkMode ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: ThemeColors.backGroundColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main widget:

```
class ClienteApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLogged;
  final bool theme;
  const ClienteApp({Key? key, required this.isLogged, required this.theme}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Customer App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: Styles.themeData(context),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: (theme) ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      initialRoute: (isLogged) ? '/home' : '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const LoginPage(),
        '/newuser': (context) => const NewUserScreen(),
        '/lostpassword': (context) => const LostPasswordIndexPage(),
        '/home': (context) => DefaultBottomBarController(child: const HomePage()),
      },
      navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorState,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`theme: Styles.themeData(context)`, won't work because MediaQuery is integrated into the widget tree only after MaterialApp is created, and therefore the MediaQuery instance cannot be found.

You shouldn't create a theme connection with `MaterialApp` based on a condition.

> Just to give an idea, you can keep the reasoning behind why the dark or light theme should be active in a separate class and manage that reasoning on the initial screen in a logical way.